# Regarding this interpretation of the pair correlation function

Tags: statistical-mechanics, fermions

On some lecture notes of the statistical mechanics of Fermi systems I found the following, specifically regarding spin 1/2 systems:

> The correlation function
>   $$
> g_{\uparrow\uparrow}(s) \equiv \frac{1}{n_\uparrow^2}
> \langle
> \psi_\uparrow^\dagger({\bf r})
> \psi_\uparrow^\dagger({\bf r}+{\bf s})
> \psi_\uparrow({\bf r}+{\bf s})
> \psi_\uparrow({\bf r})
> \rangle
> $$
>   yields the amplitude of the process of removing two particles from positions ${\bf r}$ and ${\bf r} + {\bf s}$, returning back to the same state after replacing the particles in the same positions. Thus, they are proportional to the probability of finding two particles of parallel spin a distance ${\bf s}$ apart.

(note: the average is the operator average on the ground state a $T=0K$)

While the formalism of position creation and annihilation operators is clear to me, I don't understand the given interpretation of this function. Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Could you include a link to the notes?

Comment: I'm afraid I can't, since these are the (unpublished) professor's notes for the course

Comment: This is just g(2)  - second order coherence function, used here in real space (commonly used in state space). Gordon Baym's QM book explains it exactly on second quantization chapter. Furthermore, any book on quantum optics (such as Scully's quantum optics), and even classical optics (such as Goodman's statistical optics) will explain the meaning of it.